# How to get the rows of maximum of a variable in a data frame based on their group?

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse

I'm using dplyr package in RStudio to handle my data. I have a dataframe (`df_acc`) with multiple variables. 
I would like to get the maximum value of a variable (acceleration) and get the time variable associated with it based on their group. The group of data, acceleration, and time should be saved in another dataframe called `df_acc_max`.

However, I don't know how I should get the time associated with each group ID.

The code below just gives me the max values:

```
df_acc_max <- df_acc %>%
  group_by(Channel_ID) %>%
  summarise(max_acc = max(Acceleration))

  Channel_ID max_acc
  <chr>        <dbl>
1 01.HNN       0.188
2 02.HNE       0.172
3 03.HNZ       0.115
4 04.HNE       0.372
5 05.HNN       0.269
6 06.HNE       0.412
```

Tried the code below:

```
df_acc_max <- df_acc %>%
  group_by(Channel_ID) %>%
  summarise(summarise(max_acc = max(Acceleration)))
  cbind (Time = df_acc$Time[which.max(df_acc$Acceleration)])
```

But it gives me wrong answer (same value for all of the channels):

```
   Channel_ID   max_acc   Time
1      01.HNN 0.1883840 52.255
2      02.HNE 0.1719885 52.255
3      03.HNZ 0.1145866 52.255
4      04.HNE 0.3717064 52.255
5      05.HNN 0.2691152 52.255
6      06.HNE 0.4118312 52.255
```

Comment: Hi maryam! The reason you're getting the wrong answer with your current solution is that your last statement, `cbind()`, isn't a tidyverse function and isn't group-aware. `which.max()` is just selecting a single row for the whole data frame, and then it just recycles it (pastes the single row to itself) to fill out the data frame.

Comment: Usually if you want to join columns conditionally, I'd recommend using one of the `*_join()` functions in dplyr. But in this case @Giuliano has a better solution below: instead of `summarise()`ing, you can use `filter()` to get the largest acceleration (and its associated time) for each channel group without any binding or joining :)

Comment: `df_acc %>%
  group_by(Channel_ID) %>% top_n(1, Acceleration)`

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
df_acc_max <- df_acc %>%
  group_by(Channel_ID) %>%
  filter(Acceleration == max(Acceleration))
```

Comment: I like this solution! I think it's worth highlighting in the answer that `filter()` usually selects rows meeting a condition, whereas `summarise()` condenses groups of rows into one row. But since `filter()` is being used with `max()`, which returns a single value, it ends up functioning the same way as `summarise()`, returning one row for each group. And since `filter()` doesn't touch the other columns, you get to keep the `Time` as well!

Comment: Thank you! It was very smart solution!
Got it working